# Hector_SLAM vs Gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, gmapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am currently using a laser scan message for range and encoders for odometry, should I only be looking at gmapping since I see most of the uses of hector_slam are without odometry. Or should I try both and see which method obtains better results?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214423/hector_slam-vs-gmapping/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hector_Slam can be used with or without odometry, so either way, you will be fine. I would say try both and see which one gives you better results.

---

Originally posted by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) with karma: 101 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0